# Three table join with matched and unmatched records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

- store
- article_to_store
- article table.

```
    CREATE TABLE store (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE article_to store (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `article_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `Price`....,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    
    CREATE TABLE article (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need all articles with the store name. For all articles, I want to list all stores

`store` table contains 3 stores.
`article` table contains 2 articles.

`article_to_store` relation table maybe has 2 records. One article in 2 stores.

I need a mysql query with this result:

| store.name | article_to_store.id | article.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | 1 | Pen |
| Store 2 | 2 | Pen |
| Store 3 | null | Pen |
| Store 1 | null | Erase |
| Store 2 | null | Erase |
| Store 3 | null | Erase |

```
SELECT store.name, article.name, article_to_store.id 

FROM store, article_to_store, article 

Group by store.id, article.id
ORDER BY article.id, store.id
```

If I use simple join the article_to_store table always id = 1

If I use LEFT JOIN, don't get the unmatched records.

When I remove the group by then I got 12 records.

3 stores * 2 article_to_store * 2 article = 12 record. Thats not good for me.

I would like to 3 stores * 2 article = 6 record with article_to store data if exist.

I tried many join types, but it doesn't work. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Instead of describing your schema in words, it's much easier and less ambiguous for us if you just provide the relevant CREATE TABLE statements. And share some sample data from each table, please. All you've shown us is the expected result, not the original data.

Comment: `...try many join type, but doesn't work`...what exact code did you use? What error did you get? Please always tell us exactly about your problem. Vague descriptions are useless to other programmers. JOIN queries are usually very straightforward, though, so maybe you just made some tiny mistake. We don't know what to tell you to fix though since you didn't share anything.

Comment: its just joins.  did you ever use join ?

Comment: You don't need to share everything necessarily. Reduce it to a [mre] - i.e. just enough code and data to demonstrate the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for showing the tables. Now you need to show the JOIN query you wrote and explain exactly what error/problem occurred when you tried to use it. And you also need to show sample source data from the tables (which would match the sample expected result you've provided already)

Comment: P.S. Hint: I suspect what you're probably looking for here is a `CROSS JOIN`, if you're trying to get all the possible combinations of values from article and store without there being a link via the article_store table.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why do you GROUP BY? (No aggregate functions are involved.) Also, the GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (Will do, when you upgrade to a newer MySQL version, unless in compatibility mode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` to achieve this.

```
SELECT s.name, ats.id, a.name
FROM article a
CROSS JOIN store s
LEFT JOIN article_to_store ats ON a.id = ats.article_id AND s.id = ats.store_id
ORDER BY a.id, s.id
```

A bit of an unusual scenario, but here, you're essentially asking "For every article, I want to list all stores - that's a `cross join`".  Then to get the middle column, you're only sometimes expecting a row back, which is a `left join`.

Comment: I get similar with my query. I get12 record not just 6.
3 stores * 2 article_to_store * 2 article = 12 record. 

I would like to 3 stores * 2 article = 6 record with article_to store data if exist.

Comment: Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udB9WJywBGLDwUy373UwVM/0

Comment: Many thx, works for me, I checked again and left something in the old query inside.